# I’m making a breakout game put my paddle keeps exceeding the boundary, how can I fix this

Tags: breakout

```
double right = xCenter + (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2);
double left = xCenter - (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2);

paddle.setLocation(   xCenter - (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2) , PADDLE_Y_OFFSET );
if (left == getWidth()|| right != getWidth()) {
    paddle.setLocation(xCenter - (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2) , PADDLE_Y_OFFSET );
}
```

Comment: What does getWidth() return? The canvas width? The if statement is superfluous, as it does exactely the same as the line before it.

Comment: What is `getWidth()`? Do you mean to check instead, something like `left < 0 || right > getWidth()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (pseudo code):

```
if left < leftBoundary then setLocation (leftBoundary)
if right > rightBounday then setLocation (rightBoundart - paddleWidth)
```

assuming than setLocation takes the left corner of the paddle for a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly test to see if any part of the paddle exceeds the boundary conditions. Rather than using 'if(left == getWidth() || right != getWidth())' use inequalities '>' or '<' to test if the position lies within the border.